# Setting permissions on folder not working

Tags: 2010, permissions, folder

I am using SharePoint 2010.

I set permissions on my folder but yet everyone can still see and access the documents in the folder. What is going on here?

Comment: You aren't signed in as the Farm admin, or site collection administrator?

Comment: This finally did it! [http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/67142/sharepoint-permissions-not-working][1]


  [1]: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/67142/sharepoint-permissions-not-working

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem but with site. I must edited permission on v4 site.

Maybe other users are in group "Members of this site"? 
Anyone have access to this folder? Any user/group?

Comment: Authenticated Users have READ access to the site and document library.

Comment: OK, but any others users, groups have access to your folder?

Comment: Yes, 1 group and 1 user.

Comment: Stop the inheritance and delete group - add permission only for you