# SharePoint Permissions not working

Tags: 2010, document-library, permissions, security

I am using SharePoint 2010.

When I set permissions (I Only grand myself access) on a document library or folder or document EVERYONE can still see it and download the documents. Why is that? What is going on here?

Comment: Did you break list permissions and then removed all other user's permissions except your's user account? http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/154/t/14669.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check Site Collection Administrators group.

Check Web Application Permission Policies so that these users aren't included in a policy granting them read/write permission to the web application.

Comment: Thank you, they were all added in the Web Application as Full Read!

Comment: It shouldn't matter what permission they got at web application level but if you break list permissions and remove users you don't want to give permission to then they shouldn't be able to view list or perform other operations/

Comment: Incorrect, permissions given using Web Application permission policies override permissions on site collection level.